# Android deleteIntent not working? What's wrong with my code?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, alarmmanager

I'm trying to detect when one of my notifications is cleared (either by swiping it away individually, or through the "delete all" notifications button). I'm trying to dismiss an AlarmManager alarm, but so far, it hasn't been working for me. What's wrong with my code?

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.flag_red_large, reminderName, System.currentTimeMillis());

notif.deleteIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, notifID, new Intent(this, CleanUpIntent.class), 0);

    //Destroy the activity/notification.
    finish();

}

class CleanUpIntent extends IntentService {
    public CleanUpIntent() {
        super("CleanUpIntent");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>" + "Repeating Alarm Cancelled...");

        Intent i = new Intent("com.utilityapps.YouForgotWhat.DisplayReminderNotification");
        int reminderID = i.getExtras().getInt("reminderID");

        PendingIntent displayIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, reminderID, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 

        alarmManager.cancel(displayIntent);
        displayIntent.cancel();
        }

    }

}
```

As you can see, I threw in a `System.out.println()` into my sub-class to check to see if my code is even reaching that class. I can't see that line in my LogCat output, so I'm assuming that for some reason, my `PendingIntent.getService()` line isn't working. How do I fix this issue? Thanks! :D

Comment: Please remember to tag your question with the language it pertains to. A tag of `delete` is not nearly as helpful as `java`.

Comment: No problem - just a friendly reminder :). Tagging your questions with broader tags like `java` will usually attract more attention, plus a language tag enables code coloring.

Comment: You ever get an answer to this?